# Adding values through iterating child nodes

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: My firebase-database structure click here]

And my function code in node.js:

```
exports.addFunction = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{uid}/GyroScope X-axis')
    .onWrite(event => {

var add = 0;
const addGyroX = admin.database().ref('/GyroXaddition');
const userRef = event.data.adminRef;  

userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(childrensnap => {
      var reading = childrensnap.key;
      var childData = reading.val();
      add = add+childData;
    });
  });
      return addGyroX.set(add); 
});
```

My plan is to just iterate through the GyroScope X-axis values under it and add the values, for example in 1st iteration(0.004...555 from fig) and in second iteration(0.002...645), add those values and update the result to different path if exists or create the path and set the result. I'm not getting any error but it isn't updating either, it is updating 0 not the added value. Which part of the code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're setting `0` every time. You're also not returning a promise after loading the data, which means your function might get aborted at any time after the final `});`.

This is a better variant:

```
exports.addFunction = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{uid}/GyroScope X-axis')
    .onWrite(event => {

  var add = 0;
  const addGyroX = admin.database().ref('/GyroXaddition');
  const userRef = event.data.adminRef;  

  return userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(childrensnap => {
      var reading = childrensnap.key;
      var childData = reading.val();
      add = add+childData;
    });
    return addGyroX.set(add); 
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried the above modified code but nothing is getting updated, not either 0 now. Am I iterating it correct?

Comment: There are more problems in your code. For example `reading.val()` will return a string, since you're storing the values as strings. Calling `parseFloat(reading.val())` will convert that. But this has nothing to do with Cloud Functions and can also be reproduced with the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK. I recommend that you first try to create the same functionality in a JavaScript page, which makes it a lot easier to debug. Once it works there, porting it to a Cloud Function will be a lot easier.